# SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences (String name, int mode)

Tags: android

I was reading about  `SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences (String name, int mode)` from here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String,int)

The explation is as such: 
Retrieve and hold the contents of the preferences file `name`, returning a `SharedPreferences` through which you can retrieve and modify its values. ***Only one instance of the SharedPreferences object is returned to any callers for the same name,*** ***meaning they will see each other's edits as soon as they are made.*** Can someone explain the bold+ italic line. Who will see each other? And what are edits: Are change in values known as edits ? Does same name implies the name of file in res/xml? and who are callers ? Can someone explain with example.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Only one instance of the SharedPreferences object is returned to any
>   callers for the same name, meaning they will see each other's edits as
>   soon as they are made.

it means that everyone who calls `getSharedPreferences` with the same `name` will get the same instance. It acts like a singleton, more or less.

> Who will see each other, and who are callers ?

You can think of an App, like an entity composed by different clients. E.g. two different Activities, or two different Fragments. If one of the clients make a changes, all the other will see the very same change.

> does same name implies the name of file in res/xml?

it does. It is actually is a file called `name.xml`, saved on the private storage of your app.

Comment: Thanks a lot , I have one more question I want to master(become pro in)  android app development how much time I should take and doing online course is better or reading from android developers site and making by myself as i get stuck to very small things

Comment: From what I heard, commonsware's book is really good. Honestly I never took online courses, so I couldn't really recommend something. Maybe udacity ?

Comment: Where can i find private storage for getting this name.xml file? learning from udacity only

Comment: The file is stored under /data/data/your.package.app/ you need a rooted device to access /data/data