# Cannot get data after change sharedPreferences Name

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Hello I want ask about sharedPreferences, when I first run my app with sharedPreferences name "MY_Prefs". I can insert and read data from sharedPreferences, after that I change sharedPrefrences name to `context.getPackagetName()` and I cannot get data from sharedPrefrences.

maybe someone can give me solution? I try delete file shared_pref from device, but still cannot get data.

Thanks.

Comment: could you please provide some code ?

Comment: if you don't post the code you used, we can't help you

Comment: I think the code is not the problem, but the name I use and changed. I try to create new project with same code and app is run, but when I change the name of SharedPreferences. the app cannot get data.

Comment: you can follow this answer to solve your problem :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55644253/preventing-users-to-login-again-after-closing-the-app/55644272#55644272

Answer (score 0):

If you have inserted the data in one sharedPreference Name, then you need same name to retrieve those data.

so in your case if you want to retrieve your data, you need to use your previous name that you have used insert data.

[SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences (String name, int mode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31178520/sharedpreferences-getsharedpreferences-string-name-int-mode)